# simple php - Mysql search not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$dbhost = 'xxx';
$dbuser = 'xxx';
$dbpass = 'xxx';
$dbname = 'xxx';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE FNAME='".$_POST['clientsearch']."' OR LNAME='".$_POST['clientsearch']."' OR MAIL='".$_POST['clientsearch']."' OR TEL='".$_POST['clientsearch']."'"")
or die(mysql_error());  

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 

echo "FName: ".$row['FNAME'];
echo "LNAME: ".$row['LNAME'];
echo "FName: ".$row['MAIL'];
echo "LNAME: ".$row['TEL'];

?>
```

The goal is to search my mysql database to find the result of `$_POST['clientsearch']` in one of the fields and return the lines that have that word in it (it is always 1 word)

If I use this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE FNAME='".$_POST['clientsearch']."'"")
```

it seems to work. but it only searches in the FNAME column, not all of them. Also I only get the first result back. not all.

I'm starting php/mysql so I'm a little lost and don't know all functions yet. Could someone explain how I could fix my code up?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Please oh please read this about [PHP MySQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and then read this [PHP MySQL Examples](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php) it will help you loop your results

Comment: obligatory, data sanitation mysql vulnerable comment.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data in the table and and example value of `$_POST['clientsearch']` and then your expected results ... i suspect you are looking for `like` but not really sure

Comment: should it be: `...earch']."'")` and not `...earch']."'"")`?

Comment: Aside from the above notes on SQL injection, I think it is good practise to space out your code (whatever language it is) so you don't go over a particular margin limit. I use 100 characters, but whatever works for you - it makes it more readable, and means you don't have to horizontally scroll in your IDE (or in an html code block, as per your published question).

Comment: @EscoMaji that fixed the first problem. Search now works :D. Thanks. & ManseUK will read. It's for internal use only so injection isn't really a worry but I of course need to learn about it! thank you for the links!

Comment: @ManseUK it is either a word, a number or an email adress :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you'll need to loop through each row in your result set if you're expecting more than 1 row.  I illustrate how to do this with your original code.

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$dbhost = 'xxx';
$dbuser = 'xxx';
$dbpass = 'xxx';
$dbname = 'xxx';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE FNAME='".$_POST['clientsearch']."' OR LNAME='".$_POST['clientsearch']."' OR MAIL='".$_POST['clientsearch']."' OR TEL='".$_POST['clientsearch']."'"")
or die(mysql_error());  

// Print out the contents of the entry for each row in result 
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) { 
    echo "FName: ".$row['FNAME'];
    echo "LNAME: ".$row['LNAME'];
    echo "FName: ".$row['MAIL'];
    echo "LNAME: ".$row['TEL'];

}

?>
```

Take a look in the PHP documentation on `mysql_real_escape_string` for starters on the injection stuff.

Also, as others stated you may be looking for the `LIKE` instead of `=` SQL syntax.  Also, look into the `%` wild card for `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question, but hopefully helpful. Try writing code like this:

```
$cs = mysql_escape_string($_POST['clientsearch']);
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        *
    FROM clients
    WHERE
        FNAME='$cs'
        OR LNAME='$cs'
        OR MAIL='$cs'
        OR TEL='$cs'
");
```

Exactly how you indent is up to you. This approach helps a great deal with readability, and hence also debugging :)